# Python Cookbook is for Python 2.4

Tags: python

Python Cookbook 2nd edition is updated for Python 2.4. Is it still ok to study the book using Python version 2.5 or 2.6?

Comment: Im not new to programming but Im new to python, Im looking for practical/real world examples and advanced book to learn python. Thats why Im looking at Python Cookbook. I started building django sites and decided to explore Python in depth. Sad to know that this book is not yet updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to learn out of the book.

Let me guess that you are a newbie. If you are not new to programming (probably you are not, you are in SO), then the 2.4 cookbook will be fine. There would be a few changes in the later versions to catch up with, the ones that simplify code and introduce new idioms and help you do things in a better/cleaner way, but you can pick them up later on.

If you are new to programming, then may be you should pick up something more recent. It is important to pick up clean coding habits and know your community's idioms.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.4 is too old. In my opinion it will worth the time and money to find a more recent resource, especially if your time is limited. More recent books will also cover changes in the libraries, including advances in python web app development, which I don't expect to find in aged resources. Especially for a cookbook, which includes solutions to common problems, being up-to-dated is important.

May I also say that Python is now in version 3, where major changes have been introduced. It will be beneficial to study Python 3, even if you are only planning to use 2.x versions. A great online resource is of course [Dive into Python](http://diveintopython3.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, although 2.4 is pretty old now -- not too much has changed, and what has, you can review in the [What's New in Python](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/index.html) series.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes.  There have been a few big changes since 2.4, but most if not all of the Cookbook will still apply.  It also gives you a good idea of idiomatic python.

Answer (score 1):

I find it's a useful reference and still use it. It's full of good general tips and advice much of which still applies to the newer versions of Python. That said, I'd save money and get a used copy.

I found an online version here: http://flylib.com/books/en/2.9.1.2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always start with Byte of Python OpenSource Doument Small Precise and to the Point Description. here the link :

Regards

Comment: There's no link in your answer...please edit and add it -- I'm interested. Thanks.